# "Cannot load unregistered resource /.extlib/dijit/nls/de/pickers.js"

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

A given XPages Application throws quite some errors regarding the non-existence of

```
/.extlib/dijit/nls/de/pickers.js
```

I don't know why this resource does not exist nor why it is referenced at all, I don't know where it would be referenced if it was, and I don't know whether this is a general problem of XPages in Domino 9 or if my predecessor in this job entered some code that throws this error.

So, what should this error stack tell me:

```
"Error: Unable to load /xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/dijit/nls/de/pickers.js status: 404
    at Error (native)
    at new _505 (http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js:15:134185)
    at _389 [as handleResponse] (http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js:15:94245)
    at XMLHttpRequest._395 (http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js:15:94545)
    at xhr (http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js:15:96613)
    at Object.$DDFg_ [as xhr] (http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js:15:114193)
    at Function.$DDFh_ (http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js:15:114563)
    at http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.de-de/@J&@Fi&@Jv&-dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore&-dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.IndirectSelection&-dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Menu&-dojox.grid.TreeGrid&@Eh&@EOd&@EOf&@Ek&@Eq.js:614:3871
    at Object.$DDTU_ [as forEach] (http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js:15:135758)
    at $DDOc_ (http://domino/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.de-de/@J&@Fi&@Jv&-dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore&-dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.IndirectSelection&-dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Menu&-dojox.grid.TreeGrid&@Eh&@EOd&@EOf&@Ek&@Eq.js:614:3370)"
status: 404
xhr: XMLHttpRequest
__proto__: TMP
```

By the way, is there a convenient function to search ALL XPages and user-defined controls for a certain expression?

Comment: With CTRL-H you can search within your application (or across all of your workspace).

Comment: So I now know that there is no "pickers" string in any XPages file or user-defined control of my workspace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, this is part of the Extension Library, so you won't find the JS file anywhere in your application.

Are you using local preview? If you are, you need to make sure that the ExtLib is not just installed into your designer, but also your local preview. Installation instructions for ExtLib should include that step.

If this is being run on the server, have there been any recent changes made? For example upgrading the server version without upgrading the ExtLib version?

Comment: The server has been upgraded a few months ago, I guess that could be the cause. What is ExtLib exactly - should I find it somewhere on the IBM homepage or is http://extlib.openntf.org/ the truly official channel?

Comment: That is the "official" channel. As I understand it (I haven't moved to 9 yet), much of what was in the old extension library was made truly official and included in the release of 9. This led to some conflicts with the 8.5.3 ExtLib, so need to get a version that is compatible with 9.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was caused by the documents in updatesite.nsf wasn't signed by an active user anymore. This caused extlib to not load correctly on domino 9.0.1FP7 should cause a similar issue up until FP10 though. To run the agent use Actions -> Sign all Content inside updatesite.nsf.

Paul Withers made a blog post about this issue and is covered more in depth here: https://paulswithers.github.io/blog/2023/09/18/xpages-beyond-nsf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added a link to Pauls blog post on the matter since it has been released since I made my response. But I don't really agree that the answer was unclear. If you work with domino/notes I don't think you would have much problem understanding how to follow the instructions.